# table-row and table-cell combination issue, off by 1 pixel

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I've tried to put an icon and a text next to each other so that the icon is on the left side and the text is on the right side, and both can automatically be vertically set in the middle.

I noticed some issue that the **box** of the element is for some reason **1 pixel off** that means with the text above it is not in line together. I don't know why and I've tried to change a lot of things but haven't found anything yet.

[image]

Here's a better version:
[image]

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljzmu24q/

```css
body {
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body #pageWrapper {
    margin-right: 10px;
}


/* == Content == */

div#content {
 border: 0;
}


/* ==============
        Main
   ============== */
   
/* == Default Tables == */

table.wikitable > tr > th, table.wikitable > * > tr > th {
    background: rgba(181, 181, 181, 0.27);
    border: 1px solid #676767;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

table.jquery-tablesorter th.headerSort {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#079993,#0f5182);
 background-position: right right;
    padding-right: 21px;
}

th {
    background: #1f1f1f;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 116%;
    padding: 1px 7px;
    text-align: left;
}

tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}

table.wikitable > tr > td, table.wikitable > * > tr > td {
    border: 1px solid #676767;
    padding: 0.2em;
}

table.diff, td.diff-otitle, td.diff-ntitle {
 background-color: rgba(171, 171, 171, 0.28);
}

.grid td {
 border: #5d5d5d 2px solid;
}



/* == CSS Class templates */
.colorinvert {
 filter: invert(1);
}



/* ==============
   Wiki Templates
   ============== */

.infobox,
.infoboxtable {
    background: #292929;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #4a4a4a;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 300px;
}

.infoboxtable th.infoboxname {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.infobox td, .infoboxtable td {
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.infoboxtable td.td_box {
 border: none;
 background: #1f1f1f;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 1px 7px;
 text-align: right;
}

.infoboxtable td.td_box div.icontextbox {
 display: table-row;
 height: inherit;
}
.infoboxtable td.td_box div.icontextbox .image, 
.infoboxtable td.td_box div.icontextbox .label {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.infoboxtable td.td_box div.icontextbox .label {
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
}
/*.infoboxtable td .iconlabel {
 vertical-align: top;
 float: left;
}*/


.infobox td.infoboxlabel {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) linear-gradient(#079993,#0f5182);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 1px 7px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.infobox th.infoboxname {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0) linear-gradient(#079993,#0f5182);
    border: none;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 133%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

.infoboxtable th.infoboxname {
    text-align: center;
}

.infoboxdetails {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 110%;
    padding: 0em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="infoboxtable">
<tbody><tr>
<th colspan="2" class="infoboxname">Road sign
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><a href="/File:Road_Signs.png" class="image" title="Road sign"><img alt="Road sign" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/d8/Road_Signs.png/180px-Road_Signs.png?version=076b82bec5aabff34dd511d366b3c1db" decoding="async" width="180" height="180" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/d8/Road_Signs.png/270px-Road_Signs.png?version=076b82bec5aabff34dd511d366b3c1db 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/d8/Road_Signs.png/360px-Road_Signs.png?version=076b82bec5aabff34dd511d366b3c1db 2x"></a>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" class="infoboxdetails">Description
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">Some road signs made of metal.
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" class="infoboxdetails">General
</th></tr>




<tr>
<td class="td_box" style="width:50%"><div>Stack Size</div>
</td>
<td>3
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" class="infoboxdetails">Crafting
</th></tr>


<tr>
<td class="td_box" style="width:50%"><div class="icontextbox"><div class="image"><img alt="Icon stopwatch.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/d5/Icon_stopwatch.png/30px-Icon_stopwatch.png?version=7a97f683c6f6dd2df8718d36902e2bd8" decoding="async" width="30" height="30" class="iconlabel colorinvert" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/d5/Icon_stopwatch.png/45px-Icon_stopwatch.png?version=7a97f683c6f6dd2df8718d36902e2bd8 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/d5/Icon_stopwatch.png/60px-Icon_stopwatch.png?version=7a97f683c6f6dd2df8718d36902e2bd8 2x"></div><div class="label"><div>Time to Craft</div></div></div>
</td>
<td>1.0
</td></tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" class="infoboxdetails">Ingredients
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><div style="display: inline-block;padding:1px;"><div style="position: absolute;"><a href="/Beancan_Grenade" title="Beancan Grenade"><img alt="Beancan Grenade.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/dd/Beancan_Grenade.png/50px-Beancan_Grenade.png?version=dbae46eefec6d26698b562e8f5cb1c74" decoding="async" width="50" height="50" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/dd/Beancan_Grenade.png/75px-Beancan_Grenade.png?version=dbae46eefec6d26698b562e8f5cb1c74 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/dd/Beancan_Grenade.png/100px-Beancan_Grenade.png?version=dbae46eefec6d26698b562e8f5cb1c74 2x"></a><span style="position:absolute; width:50px; height:50px; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 1;"><a href="/Beancan_Grenade" title="Beancan Grenade"><img alt="Beancan Grenade.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/dd/Beancan_Grenade.png/50px-Beancan_Grenade.png?version=dbae46eefec6d26698b562e8f5cb1c74" decoding="async" width="50" height="50" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/dd/Beancan_Grenade.png/75px-Beancan_Grenade.png?version=dbae46eefec6d26698b562e8f5cb1c74 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/d/dd/Beancan_Grenade.png/100px-Beancan_Grenade.png?version=dbae46eefec6d26698b562e8f5cb1c74 2x"></a></span></div>
<div style="display: table; height: 50px; width: 50px; overflow: hidden; line-height: normal;">
<div style="position: relative; bottom:2%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
<div style="position: relative; text-align: right; width: 98%; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: white; text-shadow: -1px 0 0.2em black, 0 1px 0.2em black, 1px 0 0.2em black, 0 -1px 0.2em black; z-index:99999;">x4</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;padding:1px;"><div style="position: absolute;"><a href="/Small_Stash" title="Small Stash"><img alt="Small Stash.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/a/a8/Small_Stash.png/50px-Small_Stash.png?version=5927ae4d0b327eea50f216a4882757be" decoding="async" width="50" height="50" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/a/a8/Small_Stash.png/75px-Small_Stash.png?version=5927ae4d0b327eea50f216a4882757be 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/a/a8/Small_Stash.png/100px-Small_Stash.png?version=5927ae4d0b327eea50f216a4882757be 2x"></a><span style="position:absolute; width:50px; height:50px; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 1;"><a href="/Small_Stash" title="Small Stash"><img alt="Small Stash.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/a/a8/Small_Stash.png/50px-Small_Stash.png?version=5927ae4d0b327eea50f216a4882757be" decoding="async" width="50" height="50" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/a/a8/Small_Stash.png/75px-Small_Stash.png?version=5927ae4d0b327eea50f216a4882757be 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/a/a8/Small_Stash.png/100px-Small_Stash.png?version=5927ae4d0b327eea50f216a4882757be 2x"></a></span></div>
<div style="display: table; height: 50px; width: 50px; overflow: hidden; line-height: normal;">
<div style="position: relative; bottom:2%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
<div style="position: relative; text-align: right; width: 98%; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: white; text-shadow: -1px 0 0.2em black, 0 1px 0.2em black, 1px 0 0.2em black, 0 -1px 0.2em black; z-index:99999;">x1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;padding:1px;"><div style="position: absolute;"><a href="/Rope" title="Rope"><img alt="Rope.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/b/b4/Rope.png/50px-Rope.png?version=c1e469a98e537e4d5cdb9ce338d57b77" decoding="async" width="50" height="50" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/b/b4/Rope.png/75px-Rope.png?version=c1e469a98e537e4d5cdb9ce338d57b77 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/b/b4/Rope.png/100px-Rope.png?version=c1e469a98e537e4d5cdb9ce338d57b77 2x"></a><span style="position:absolute; width:50px; height:50px; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 1;"><a href="/Rope" title="Rope"><img alt="Rope.png" src="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/b/b4/Rope.png/50px-Rope.png?version=c1e469a98e537e4d5cdb9ce338d57b77" decoding="async" width="50" height="50" srcset="https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/b/b4/Rope.png/75px-Rope.png?version=c1e469a98e537e4d5cdb9ce338d57b77 1.5x, https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/rust_gamepedia/thumb/b/b4/Rope.png/100px-Rope.png?version=c1e469a98e537e4d5cdb9ce338d57b77 2x"></a></span></div>
<div style="display: table; height: 50px; width: 50px; overflow: hidden; line-height: normal;">
<div style="position: relative; bottom:2%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
<div style="position: relative; text-align: right; width: 98%; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: white; text-shadow: -1px 0 0.2em black, 0 1px 0.2em black, 1px 0 0.2em black, 0 -1px 0.2em black; z-index:99999;">x1</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

The class the table is using is `infoboxtable` and the code is at the `td.td_box`

My question is, why is it off by 1 pixel and how can I fix it? I've tried to also compare it by changing *"Time to Craft"* to the same as above, *"Stack Size"* to see the difference better

Comment: try to have the *stack size* on the same nested structure but without the icon to make sure it will be the same

Comment: what nested structure as in copy paste the one with the icon? But is it possible to fix it without having to copy paste the table? I mean it's one pixel that is missing, what went wrong? I can't even margin it.

Comment: I don't know as I am not able to see the 1px you are talking about..

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've made a line in photoshop now https://i.imgur.com/ijlFyjg.png

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've answered my question are you able to tell me what happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-spacing: 0;`
on `td.td_box` seemed to have fixed it and also changed it for the one on the top, I can't really explain why or how it really happend like if it generated an extra border while I nested it in the tables?

Comment: I also thought about border-spacing but it changed nothing for me when I tried. It seems logical since by default there 2px border-spacing applied to any table elements so it can explain the extra 1px on the right and probably another on the left

Comment: but would display: table-row or something already add a border-spacing?